# What is the OID address for getting the CPU loading & physical RAM usage in WinXPsp3 & WinServer2003r2sp2 via SNMP?

Tags: windows-xp, snmp, memory, cpu-usage, windows-server-2003-r2

I am trying to use snmp to get the usage of CPU & physical RAM from remote PC (WinXPsp3 & WinServer2003r2sp2), after google many hours I did not find any exactly OID address for them. I have used the OidView to test and check but too many OID displayed in OidView, how do I know which OID is I need? The value I need is like the value in windows Task Manager.

Question: What is the OID address for getting the CPU loading & physical RAM usage in WinXPsp3 & WinServer2003r2sp2 via SNMP?

Any help you guys can give would be gratefully received!

Mike Shieh.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is a specific OID for this, I always had trouble. However, there is a freeware SNMP extension called SNMP informant you can install that lights up some aggregate perfmon counters as OIDs that are more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

There is limited support for 'useful' SNMP data in the default 2k3 installation. Some services will configure SNMP support, *if* snmp is installed before the service (IIS comes to mind).

Take a look at [Getif](http://www.snmp4tpc.com/getif.htm) - by default it should show you the default oid's in 2k3, and is expandable by adding MIB's to it. You can also walk the OID tree.

Hardware and Software SNMP support can be easily added.

- Your hardware vendor may provide OS specific SNMP support tools and granular hardware MIBs.
- [SNMP Informant Free Edition](http://www.wtcs.org/informant/download.htm). Up to date, and provides 'system health' counters.  Be sure to check out the author's [original web site](http://www.snmp4tpc.com/), which has useful (if a little dated) detail about SNMP on Windows NT devices.
- [Net-SNMP](http://www.net-snmp.org/), provides 'system health' counters, management tools.